# What is the best way to trigger actions on successful authentication in ASP.NET MVC Core?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When multiple authentication schemes are registered there can be many different paths that a successful authentication can take. I'm looking for a way to register a single handler which will trigger actions that should be taken upon any successful auth.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most robust solution I've found is to subclass `SignInManager` and override the `SignInAsync` or `SignInWithClaimsAsync` method:

```
public class CustomSignInManager<TUser> : SignInManager<TUser> where TUser : class
{
    public CustomSignInManager(UserManager<TUser> userManager, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<TUser> claimsFactory, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor, ILogger<SignInManager<TUser>> logger, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
        : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, logger, schemes, new DefaultUserConfirmation<TUser>()) { }

    public override async Task SignInWithClaimsAsync(TUser user, AuthenticationProperties authenticationProperties, IEnumerable<Claim> additionalClaims)
    {
        await base.SignInWithClaimsAsync(user, authenticationProperties, additionalClaims);

        // Trigger custom actions
    }
}
```

Then register the custom SignInManager in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddSignInManager<CustomSignInManager<TUser>>();
```